# How do I make the Airbrush tool size, match the size of the clipboard, in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, tools

With GIMP, it is possible to select and copy a region of the image to the clipboard, and then use this region as the brush for the Airbrush tool.

However, the size of the 'painted' region, is controlled by the Airbrush size, and will scale (I believe) the region in the clipboard to match this.

Other than setting the size manually by eye, **is there a way to make the Airbrush 'spray' a region with a size identical to the original?**

Answer (score 1):

In Gimp 2.8 we can adjust the airbrush size to match the size of the clipboard with a button on the right side of the size slider in the tool options tab:

[image]